# Static files are interpreted as Documents while having a different MIME type

Tags: google-app-engine, web

I'm setting up a static website With the Google App Engine and my files aren't being served properly.

Example:
https://shawnfunke.appspot.com/images/icon_144x.png

Following this URL will give you a `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/png: "https://shawnfunke.appspot.com/images/icon_144x.png".`
Warning and the PNG couldn't be loaded.

The same happens with other static files such as `https://shawnfunke.appspot.com/css/style.css` and `https://shawnfunke.appspot.com/manifest.json` but those still work.

This image [image: REQUEST] shows the type is set to `Document` I don't know why, but the response [image: RESPONSE] shows the correct MIME type `image/png`.

The static content should be served with the expected type / (CSS File/ Image / JSON File).

This is the `app.yaml`

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html
  secure: always

- url: /privacy
  static_files: www/pages/privacy.html
  upload: www/pages/privacy.html
  secure: always

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
  secure: always
```

The website can be viewed at https://shawnfunke.appspot.com

I've already tried using Chrome Stable and Firefox. It works fine on the local Development server from the Google Cloud SDK.
The files also show properly on my local PC and can also be viewed at https://github.com/ShawnFunke/website/tree/master/www/images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be resolved. I haven't changed my `app.yaml` and the images since, so sadly I don't know what the real issue was.